# How to get Bootstrap Jumbotron not to lose its height without showing the white space when testing in a browser

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design, media-queries

I'm having an issue with my jumbotron not scaling properly when i'm trying to test my website. My height changes every time I adjust the size of the browser, which cause it to show the white space. Is there a way to set the height for the jumbotron without showing the white space?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

<!-- Mobile Specific Metas
    ================================================== -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>The Portfolio of Jason Murray</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Font awesome css file-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <!-- Default Theme css file -->
    <link id="orginal" href="css/default-theme.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Google fonts -->
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Varela' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

</head>

<body>
    <!--=========== HEADER SECTION ================-->
    <header id="header">
      <!-- BEGIN MENU -->
      <div class="menu_area">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation"> 
          <div class="container">
          <div class="navbar-header">
            <!-- FOR MOBILE VIEW COLLAPSED BUTTON -->
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
              <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>

            <!-- LOGO -->
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">Jason<span>Murray</span></a>
          </div>

          <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul id="top-menu" class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right main_nav">
              <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
              <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
              <li><a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>               
              <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>                           
            </ul>           
          </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
          </div>     
        </nav>  
      </div><!-- END MENU -->
    </header>
     <!--=========== END HEADER SECTION ================-->

    <!--=========== MAIN CONTENT SECTION ================-->
    <div class="jumbotron">         
        <div class="container">
            <div class="image_opacity"></div> 
            <div class="caption">
                <h2>Front-End</h2> 
                <h2>Web Developer</h2>
                <p>Hi, I'm Jason Murray and I have a passion for building simplistic websites.</p>
                <a href="#" class="caption_btn">Recent Work</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--=========== END MAIN CONTENT SECTION ================-->

    <!--=========== FOOTER SECTION================-->
     <footer id="footer">
       <div class="container">
         <div class="row">
           <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
             <div class="footer_left">
               <p>&copy; 2015 <a href="index.html" target="_blank">Jason Murray Web Design</a>. All Rights Reserved</p>
             </div>
           </div>
           <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
             <div class="footer_right">
               <ul class="social_nav">
                 <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
                 <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
                 <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a></li>
               </ul>
             </div>
           </div>
         </div>
       </div>
     </footer>
    <!--=========== END FOOTER SECTION================-->
    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

CSS:

```
body,html{
  overflow-x:hidden;
}
html{
  height: 100%;
}
body {
 font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  overflow-x: hidden !important;
}

ul{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

a{ 
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #2f2f2f;

}
a:focus{
  outline: none;
  text-decoration: none;
}
h1,h2{
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif; 
}
h3,h4,h5,h6{
    font-family: 'Varela', sans-serif;  
}

h2 {
  color: #313338;  
  font-size: 72px;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 57px;
  margin: 0;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
img{
 border:none;
}

/*--------------------*/
/* HEADER */
/*--------------------*/

#header{
  float: left;
  display: inline;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

/*--------.menu_area-------- */
.menu_area{
  position: absolute;
  left:0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}
.navbar-default {
  background-color: #000000;
  border-color: transparent;
  padding: 12px 0px;
}
.past-main {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
  margin-top: 0px;
  padding:6px 0px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;
  transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;

}
#navbar{overflow-x: hidden;}

.navbar-brand {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
  color: #fff !important;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bolder;
  font-family: 'Varela', sans-serif;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus {
  background-color: transparent;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover{
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #2da2c8;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:focus {
  background-color: transparent;
  color: #2da2c8;
}
.navbar-brand > span {
  color: #2da2c8;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus { 
  color: #2da2c8;
}


/*---------------------*/
/* MAIN CONTENT - HOME */
/*---------------------*/
.jumbotron {
  background: url("../img/lucho-49.jpg") no-repeat center center;
  -webkit-background-size: 100% 100%
  -moz-background-size: 100% 100%;
  -o-background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  margin-top: 75px;
  height: 305px;
}
.image_opacity{
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #242434;
  margin-top: 75px;
  opacity: 0.8;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 305px;
  z-index: 9;
}
.caption {
  margin-top: 17%;
  padding: 5px 0;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 999;
}
.caption > h2 {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 12px;
  margin: 0 auto 10px;
  padding-bottom: 8px;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  width: 90%;
}
.caption>p{
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 12px;    
}
.caption_btn{
    padding: 10px 15px;
    border: 2px solid #fff;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 12px;
    display: inline-block;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.caption_btn:hover,.caption_btn:focus{
    border-color:#2da2c8;
    color: #2da2c8;
    text-decoration: none;
}

/*----------------------*/
/* MAIN CONTENT - ABOUT */
/*----------------------*/

#about {
  display: inline;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 80px 0px;
}
.about_area{
  float: left;
  display: inline;
  margin-bottom: 140px;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 200px;
}
.heading{
  float: left;
  display: inline;
  width: 100%;
}
.heading h2 {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: 35px;
  margin-top: 65px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  padding-right: 50px;
  font-size: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
}
.heading p{
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 28px;
  font-weight: 300;
}
.about_content{
  float: left;
  display: inline;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 50px 0px;
}
.about_featured{
  float: left;
  display: inline;
  width: 100%;
}
.panel-group .panel {
  border-radius: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  box-shadow: none;
}
.panel-group .panel + .panel {
  margin-top: 0;
}
.panel-default {
  border-color: transparent;
}
.panel-default > .panel-heading {
  background-color: transparent;
  color: #333;
  border: 0 none !important;
  padding: 5px 15px;
}
.panel-title {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  color: #222;
  font-family: 'Varela', sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}
.panel-title a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}
.panel-default .in{ 
  padding-left:10px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s;
  transition: all 0.5s; 
}
.panel-title a span{
  margin-right: 5px;
}
.panel-body { 
  border-top-color: transparent !important;
  padding: 0px 15px;
  margin: 10px 0px;
}
.about_slider{
  float: left;
  display: inline;
  width: 100%;
  height: 350px;
}
.single_iteam{
  float: left;
  display: inline;
  width: 100%;
  height:100%;
}
.single_iteam img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
.about_slider .slick-dots li button:before {
  content: "•";
  font-size: 28px;  
}
.about_slider .slick-dots li.slick-active button:before {
  opacity: 0.75;
}
.skills_area{
  background-color: #fff
  float: left;
  display: inline;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 350px;
  padding: 85px 0px;
  position: relative;
}
.skills{
  position: relative;
  z-index: 999;
}
.heading h3 {
  color: #000;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  font-size: 40px;
  margin: 0 0 40px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 40px;
}
div[data-dimension] {
  float: none;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.circle-text{
  color: #000;
}
.single_skill{
  float: left;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
.single_skill > h4 {
  color: #000000;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

/*--------------------------*/
/* MAIN CONTENT - PORTFOLIO */
/*--------------------------*/

/*------------------------*/
/* MAIN CONTENT - CONTACT */
/*------------------------*/

/*--------------------*/
/* FOOTER */
/*--------------------*/

#footer{
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #000;
}
.footer_left{
  float: left;
  display: inline;
  width: 100%;
}
.footer_left > p {
  font-size: 12px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ffffff;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  margin-top: 5px;
}
.footer_left > p a {  
  font-weight: bold;
}
.footer_right{
  float: left;
  display: inline;
  width: 100%;
}
.social_nav{
  text-align: center;  
}
.social_nav li{
  display: inline-block;
}
.social_nav li a {
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  color: #ffffff;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 18px;
  height: 30px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 35px;
  line-height: 28px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}
.social_nav li a:hover{
  color: #2da2c8;
  border-color: #2da2c8; 
}

/*----------------------------------*/
/* RESPONSIVE STYLE - MEDIA QUERIES */
/*----------------------------------*/

/* Landscape phones and portrait tablets */
@media(min-width: 481px) and (max-width: 767px) {
.navbar-brand {color: #fff !important;font-size: 26px;font-weight: bolder;font-family: 'Varela', sans-serif;}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {font-size: 12px;}
.jumbotron {background: url("../img/lucho-49.jpg") no-repeat center center;-webkit-background-size: 100% 100%;-moz-background-size: 100% 100%;-o-background-size: 100% 100%;background-size: 100% 100%;height: 592px;}
.image_opacity{background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #242434;margin-top: 75px;height: 592px;opacity: 0.8;width: 100%;}
.caption {margin-top: 40%;position: relative;text-align: center;z-index: 999;}
.caption > h2 {color: #ffffff;font-size: 25px;font-weight: 700;line-height: 20px;margin: 0 auto 10px;padding-bottom: 8px;text-align: center;text-transform: uppercase;width: 90%;}
.caption> p {color: #ffffff;font-size: 14px;}
.caption_btn{padding: 10px 15px;border: 2px solid #fff;color: #fff;font-size: 14px;display: inline-block;text-transform: uppercase;}
.caption_btn:hover,.caption_btn:focus {border-color:#2da2c8;color: #2da2c8;text-decoration: none;}
#footer{padding: 24px;}
#footer > .container > .row {margin-right: auto;}
.footer_left > p {font-size: 12px;text-align: center;}
.social_nav{text-align: center;}
}
/* Portrait tablets and small desktops */
@media(min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {
.navbar-brand {color: #fff !important;font-size: 30px;font-weight: bolder;font-family: 'Varela', sans-serif;}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {font-size: 13px;}
.jumbotron {background: url("../img/lucho-49.jpg") no-repeat center center;-webkit-background-size: 100% 100%;-moz-background-size: 100% 100%;-o-background-size: 100% 100%;background-size: 100% 100%;height: 816px;}
.image_opacity{background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #242434;margin-top: 75px;height: 816px;opacity: 0.8;width: 100%;}
.caption {margin-top: 28%;position: relative;text-align: center;z-index: 999;}
.caption > h2 {color: #ffffff;font-size: 45px;font-weight: 700;line-height: 56px;margin: 0 auto 10px;padding-bottom: 8px;text-align: center;text-transform: uppercase;width: 90%;}
.caption> p {color: #ffffff;font-size: 18px;}
.caption_btn{padding: 10px 15px;border: 2px solid #fff;color: #fff;font-size: 18px;display: inline-block;text-transform: uppercase;}
.caption_btn:hover,.caption_btn:focus {border-color:#2da2c8;color: #2da2c8;text-decoration: none;}
#footer{padding: 35px;}
#footer > .container {margin-left:-15px;margin-right:-15px;}
.footer_left > p {font-size: 13px;text-align: left;}
#footer .row {margin-left: -26px;}
.social_nav{text-align: right;margin-right: 12px;}
}

/* Landscape tablets and medium desktops */
@media (min-width: 992px) and (max-width: 1199px) {
.navbar-brand {color: #fff !important;font-size: 33px;font-weight: bolder;font-family: 'Varela', sans-serif;}
.container > .navbar-header {margin-left:8px;}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {font-size: 14px;}
.navbar-right {margin-right:0px;}
.jumbotron {background: url("../img/lucho-49.jpg") no-repeat center center;-webkit-background-size: 100% 100%;-moz-background-size: 100% 100%;-o-background-size: 100% 100%;background-size: 100% 100%;height: 1024px;}
.image_opacity{background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #242434;margin-top: 75px;height: 1024px;opacity: 0.8;width: 100%;}
.caption {margin-top: 32%;position: relative;text-align: center;z-index: 999;}
.caption > h2 {color: #ffffff;font-size: 55px;font-weight: 700;line-height: 66px;margin: 0 auto 10px;padding-bottom: 8px;text-align: center;text-transform: uppercase;width: 90%;}
.caption> p {color: #ffffff;font-size: 19px;}
.caption_btn{padding: 10px 15px;border: 2px solid #fff;color: #fff;font-size: 18px;display: inline-block;text-transform: uppercase;}
.caption_btn:hover,.caption_btn:focus {border-color:#2da2c8;color: #2da2c8;text-decoration: none;}
#footer{padding: 35px;}
#footer > .container {margin-left:-15px;margin-right:-15px;}
.footer_left > p {font-size: 14px;text-align: left;}
.social_nav{text-align: right;margin-right: 18px;}
}

/* Large desktops and laptops */
@media(min-width: 1200px) {
.navbar-brand {color: #fff !important;font-size: 35px;font-weight: bolder;font-family: 'Varela', sans-serif;}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {font-size: 15px;}
.jumbotron {background: url("../img/lucho-49.jpg") no-repeat center center;-webkit-background-size: 100% 100%;-moz-background-size: 100% 100%;-o-background-size: 100% 100%;background-size: 100% 100%;height: 740px;}
.image_opacity {background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #242434;margin-top: 75px;height: 740px;opacity: 0.8;width: 100%;}
.caption {margin-top: 10%;position: relative;text-align: center;z-index: 999;}
.caption > h2 {color: #ffffff;font-size: 65px;font-weight: 700;line-height: 76px;margin: 0 auto 10px;padding-bottom: 8px;text-align: center;text-transform: uppercase;width: 90%;}
.caption > p {color: #ffffff;font-size: 20px;}
.caption_btn {padding: 10px 15px;border: 2px solid #fff;color: #fff;font-size: 20px;display: inline-block;text-transform: uppercase;}
.caption_btn:hover,.caption_btn:focus {border-color:#2da2c8;color: #2da2c8;text-decoration: none;}
#footer{padding: 35px;}
.footer_left > p {font-size: 15px;text-align: left;}
.social_nav{text-align: right;}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd go for a different approach. The problem is, you've got fixed heights on your `jumbotron` and your `image_opacity`. A far more easy approach is putting a faux-gradient on the `jumbotron`, like this:

```
.jumbotron {
  background-image: 
      linear-gradient(rgba(249, 249, 249, 0.9), rgba(249, 249, 249, 0.9)),
      url("../img/lucho-49.jpg") no-repeat center center;
  background-size: 100% auto;
  margin-top: 75px;
  height: 400px;
  position: relative;
}
```

And then you don't need the `image_opacity`. Oh and I didn't check this thoroughly, but -webkit-, -moz-, and -o-background-size are imho non-existent.

**Edit 2**: **set the parent div and the jumbotron to a height of 100%** (in this case, that's body):

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
.jumbotron {
     background-image: 
          linear-gradient(rgba(249, 249, 249, 0.9), rgba(249, 249, 249, 0.9)),
          url("../img/lucho-49.jpg") no-repeat center center;
     background-size: 100% 100%;
     margin-bottom: 0px;
     height: 100%;
}
```

**[Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/v1eMzSWDhV)** (in this example the page is wrapped in a #wrap element, so this has to be `height:100%;`, too.)

This should do the trick. Try to put `!important` after the properties if it's not working immediately.

Comment: Have you used rgba? It works fine here. I'll edit my answer focussing on the height issue.

Comment: Yep! When I preview the site in the browser, the background image shows but not the rgba. Also, I tried it and it didn't work. I think its something to do with how I set my media queries breakpoints because when I scale the browser from min-width 1200px (desktop) to 320px (mobile), it i lose the height. Here is my media queries setting. https://jsfiddle.net/xhcr3sjm/

Comment: I edited my answer. You should make the parent (body) 100%.